# Send message from a basic server to a specific client

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have two wifi modules M1 and M2 that connect to my access point. I have an android phone that connects to the same access point. I have a socket server on my android phone and the two modules join to the server as clients. Now my question is, is it possible to send a string message from my phone to module M1 without having to send anything to M2. I want to choose between clients to send the message to. Is it even possible in Java?

Ok, here goes.

```
//setting up server
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000, 0, IPaddress);

//creating a client socket to accept it
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Now, I accept the client in a seperate thread so that the main thread does not freeze becauz `accept()` function is blocking.

I don't know how to create a new thread every time a new client connects. Also I dont know how to limit the number of clients that can connect. I need at most 5 clients and no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to maintain a separate connection to each client. The `ServerSocket` class has an `accept()` function which returns a `Socket` object. That object represents a connection between two points, your server and one client. You can call `ServerSocket.accept()` multiple times in a loop to accept all incoming connections. Each `Socket` object returned will be for a different client.

In order to have the server send a message to a specific client, it will need to know which socket belongs to which client, so the clients will have to send some message to the server identifying themselves, and the server will need to read and interpret that message. Then it can respond with the appropriate response for that specific client.

Post your code if you are still having trouble.

**UPDATE** because you added code to the question: See the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) about creating threads. That will be a lot of reading beyond this post on stackoverflow.

As to accepting connections and starting threads, just do it in a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    // start a new thread, passing it the clientSocket as an argument
}
```

Other possibly useful links:
https://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: oh man you're simply a genius. I couldn't have put that in better words myself. I knew it was possible just didn't know how to implement it. I have my code but i don't know how to put it here. when i copy and paste it shows up as junk. How do i post codes like other people do on stack overflow??

Comment: put 4 spaces before each line of your code. The `{}` button above your post when you are editing it will try to do this automatically, but it doesn't always work. Below the editing box on your post is a preview. Also, if my answer solved your problem, feel free to click the check mark beside it to indicate the issue is solved and give me a correct answer bonus.

Comment: sweet. Youre man. ill give that a shot. Be back with some code in 15mins

Comment: I'm not sure but someone deleted my post called Update 2.
Anyway I have done that but still im able to sent message to the client that connects last. Ok another question, can i do something similar without a server-client communication. I mean my phone and the two modules are connected to my access point which is LAN. Is there a way to send a message from my phone to any of the module using its IP address that I get from my router?

Comment: This really is a topic for a different question on a different stackexchange site, but your hosts (any computer connecting to your LAN, like your desktop, laptop, or phone is a host. `Modules` is a misleading term the way you use it) would need to have a server running on them listening for incoming messages. openSSH is a great and secure tool for this on linux, and the ssh protocol can be used on almost any modern OS. If you're having difficulty with your code sending messages to the wrong client, then post the code and we'll help you find the cause.

Comment: sweet az kaz. I'm in the middle of my exams so cant make any progress with the code. I will resume my project on tuesday. Also, by modules i mean wifi modules. I ordered two wifi modules and trying to hook it up to two appliances at home. I want to switch those appliances on/off using my phone.