# Send message from a hotspot to a connected client

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send message from a basic server to a specific client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777678/send-message-from-a-basic-server-to-a-specific-client)

Here is a scenario. I have enabled a hotspot through wifi tethering on my android phone. I also have two wifi modules which connects to this hotspot. Now, I want to send a message to only 'one client' (not all) connected to my hotspot. Is that even possible in Java if I dont want to use a Server-Client Application. As the hotspot itself acts as a server.

Thanks for any assistance.